# How to put data into HashMap<key, Object>

Tags: java, excel, object, hashmap

I am a new to programming. I have a program that iterates excel file and put values into hashmap HashMapbut object in a hash map is always has last record. I'll post my code and may be you can tell me my mistakes, or better yet post code how it should be done. Please help, really stuck here.

My excel file:

```
doc seq acc status  notes
1111    2   account test    value1
22222   3   account test2   value2
```

My object ....

```
public class Account{

int docNumber;
int docSequence;
String docAccCode;
String docStatus;
String docNotes;

//getters and setters bellow
......
}
```

My iterate method...

```
public void readFile() throws IOException{


    InputStream ExcelFileToRead = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
    XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(ExcelFileToRead);
    XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
    XSSFRow row = null;
    XSSFCell cell = null;

    int recordNumber = 0;

    Iterator rows = sheet.rowIterator();

    while (rows.hasNext()){
        row=(XSSFRow) rows.next();
        int rowNum = row.getRowNum();
        int cellNum = 0;
        if(rowNum != 0){
            Iterator cells = row.cellIterator();
            while (cells.hasNext()){
                cell=(XSSFCell) cells.next();

                switch(cellNum){
                case 0:
                    docMap.setDocNumber((int)cell.getNumericCellValue());
                    break;
                case 1:
                    docMap.setDocSequence((int)cell.getNumericCellValue());
                    break;
                case 2:
                    docMap.setDocAccCode(cell.getStringCellValue());
                    break;
                case 3:
                    docMap.getDocStatus(cell.getStringCellValue());
                    break;
                case 4: 
                    docMap.getDocNotes(cell.getStringCellValue());
                }   

                cellNum ++;
            }
            // docMap overwrites it's self and has last record only.
            records.put(recordNumber, docMap);

            recordNumber ++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Stuck with what? You put data into the map with, err, the put() method. Not a real question.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are using a single instance of docMap object. You need to new docMap in your while loop.

Answer (score 1):

Few point to note about your code -

1. When you say

   ```
   records.put(recordNumber, docMap);
   ```

   You just put the reference of the Account Object in the map. Since in all iterations you put the same reference all values in the Map will point to same Account object. Yes when you use setter methods all the values will be overridden but previous values will be lost. So at the end of all iterations you will have all map values containing last record only. So as others have suggested above you need to create a separate Account object every time you iterate over a row.

   ```
   Account docMap = new Account();
   ```
2. From your code I see you are trying to save details from excel sheet into your Account object and then store the account object with record number into a Map.In case 3 and 4 why have you used getter methods instead of setter. Change the getter methods to setter methods like case 0,1,2.

   ```
     switch(cellNum){
       case 0:
           docMap.setDocNumber((int)cell.getNumericCellValue());
           break;
       case 1:
           docMap.setDocSequence((int)cell.getNumericCellValue());
           break;
       case 2:
           docMap.setDocAccCode(cell.getStringCellValue());
           break;
       case 3:
           docMap.setDocStatus(cell.getStringCellValue());
           break;
       case 4: 
           docMap.setDocNotes(cell.getStringCellValue());
         }
   ```
3. I don't see your record Map defined anywhere. So you would need to define one with proper generics.

   ```
   Map<Integer,Account> records = new HashMap<Integer, Account>();
   ```
4. Also your recordNumber gives you the the order of record. So you need to increment it in each iteration over rows.

   ```
   recordNumber ++;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new instance of docMap at the point where you get the row.

Assuming the docMap is an Account Object, should be something like so:

```
while (rows.hasNext()){
    row=(XSSFRow) rows.next();
    Account docMap = new Account();
    int rowNum = row.getRowNum();
    ...
    records.put(recordNumber, docMap);
    recordNumber ++;
}
```

Otherwise you just are just placing the same Account object into your map every time while updating it to the last row of the excel file.